Who is this Mahavidya in the picture?
I have recently noticed in the picture of Jagadhatri, that there are 11 Mahavidyas.

Most of us have already know about the 10 Mahavidyas (expect the circled one). But, who is that that circled Mahavidya? Also, this Mahavidya is looks like Lord Shiva, so Is that actually Lord Shiva?
